# How to map a column to another dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to move a column `Count` from the `all_kids_df` table to the `nyc_trip_df` table as follows:

**all_kids_df** is this:

```
          Kids           City  Count
1        Sofia         Boston    1.0
3   Claire Ann  San Francisco    1.0
4          Joe        Detroit    3.0
5        Betty          Miami    2.0
7       Archie      Bruxelles    1.0
8          Joe          Paris    3.0
9         Phil         Berlin    1.0
10        Luke      Stockholm    1.0
13         Joe      Barcelona    3.0
14       Betty         Madrid    2.0
```

**nyc_trip_df** is this:

```
         Kids       City Preferred Transport
0       Sofia     Boston                 Bus
1  Claire Ann        NaN                 NaN
2         Joe    Detroit               Train
3       Betty        NaN                 Car
4      Archie  Bruxelles                 NaN
5         Joe        NaN            Airplane
6        Phil     Berlin                Ship
7        Luke        NaN            Airplane
```

`Desired table` is ny_tryp_df table, but with the associated numbers at Count.

```
      Kids       City Preferred Transport   Count
0       Sofia     Boston                 Bus    1.0
1  Claire Ann        NaN                 NaN    1.0
2         Joe    Detroit               Train    3.0
3       Betty        NaN                 Car    2.0
4      Archie  Bruxelles                 NaN    2.0
5         Joe        NaN            Airplane    3.0
6        Phil     Berlin                Ship    1.0
7        Luke        NaN            Airplane    1.0
```

How can it be resolved in an elegant way ? I can only think of arrays and so, but I think it could be resolved much easier?

Thank you a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the two dataframes. Note that on the "how", you can change "inner" to any join you prefer that best suits your needs:

```py
all_kids_df.merge(nyc_trip_df, how="inner", on=["Kids", "City"])
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not resolve the problem with none of the how possibilities. :( unfortunately

Comment: Could you expand on the reason why this didn't work? Perhaps with some more detail on the problem and what exactly you're looking for

Comment: I think I understand now. The problem here is that if your "Kids" has any duplicates, merging is going to be a nightmare. However, if you're sure you won't have any duplicates, you can change the `on=["Kids", "City"]` to `on="Kids"`